# Google cloud vision API samplesfor ruby

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-api-gateway

I am using google-cloud-ruby client library, I don't see any samples related to current implementation of google cloud vision API. From where should I look out code samples of google cloud vision API for ruby client library.

Answer (score 0):

It is hosted together with the rest of the google cloud ruby samples [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docs-samples/tree/84d219154e33eb81af2d5fee358d440b52a30f34/vision)